# Problem with ActiveMQ dependencies with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am working on an ActiveMQ project using Spring Boot. I tried to generate a project with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and import it to IntelliJ (community edition).

The problem occurred when Maven could not resolve the `spring-boot-starter-activemq` dependency.

Here is the project generated:
[image]

Something weird is that the project is synced but there still an error in the `pom.xml` file:
[image]

Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried restarting IntelliJ? Sometimes when a new project has trouble resolving dependencies restarting helps. For what it's worth, I just generated a demo project using https://start.spring.io with the same exact inputs as you, and it worked fine for me when I imported it into IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Community Edition).

Comment: Run Maven reimport procedure

Comment: thanks i will try it

Comment: restarting did not resolve the problem. and tried doing maven reload same thing.

Comment: Now the ide tried to dowload the dependency, but unfortunately this message appeared: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:pom:2.3.10.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-activemq/2.3.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-activemq-2.3.10.RELEASE.pom ProxyInfo{host='123.45.6.78', userName='null', port=80, type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok figure out that I made a mistake adding a setting.xml file with invalid proxy settings, which led to maven enable to download , now the problem is solved thanks for you guys for guiding me to the solution.